# How to Log In a user threw Facebook and save that users data in Cloud Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to log users into into my app using Facebook and then save the users into my Cloud Firestore. I'm just not too sure how to go about it. This is the code I have now

```
 @IBAction func buttTapped(_ sender: Any) {


    let fbLoginManager = LoginManager()
          fbLoginManager.logIn(permissions: ["public_profile", "email"], from: self) { (result, error) in
              if let error = error {
                  print("Failed to login: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                  return
              }

              guard let accessToken = AccessToken.current else {
                  print("Failed to get access token")
                  return
              }

              let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: accessToken.tokenString)

              // Perform login by calling Firebase APIs
              Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in
                  if let error = error {
                      print("Login error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                      let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Login Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                      let okayAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                      alertController.addAction(okayAction)
                      self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                      return
                  }

                  // Present the main view
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

              })

          }

}//
```

What code do I have to add to grab certain values like email and name and save it to Cloud Firestore the image below is an example for what I have using email signup
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just done the Facebook authentication and get the access token. To get user public info you need a graph request. The full Facebook Authentication and Graph request code will be like

```
func facebookLogin(){
     let loginManager = LoginManager()
       loginManager.logIn(permissions: [.publicProfile, .email], viewController: self) { loginResult in
                switch loginResult {
                case .failed(let error):
                    print(error)
                case .cancelled:
                    print("User cancelled login.")
                case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
                 print("Logged in!")
                 self.fetchUserProfile()
              }
        }

}

func fetchUserProfile() {
     let graphRequest : GraphRequest = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"id, email, name, picture.width(480).height(480)"])

    graphRequest.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
         if ((error) != nil)
        {
             print("Error took place: \(error ?? "" as! Error)")
        }
        else
        {
            let result = result as! Dictionary<String, Any>
            let picture = result["picture"] as! Dictionary<String, Any>
            let dataObj = picture["data"] as! Dictionary<String,Any>

            var emailValue = result["email"] as! String?

            if emailValue == nil {
                emailValue = ""
            }
            let name = result["name"] as? String
            let id = result["id"] as? String
            let imageUrl = result["url"] as? String

            // Update data to firestore 

        }
    })
}
```

Hope you understand.

Comment: thank you its given me a problem tho saying string has no member .publicProfile and .email in the facebookLogin function

Comment: Try using by this `["public_profile", "email"]` as already you have tried,

Comment: so how will that graph request code take the user information and  load it into firestore do I have to convert anything?

Comment: You need to format the data to send firestore. Graph request just provide you the profile information.

Comment: idk if the sdk was updated but the code just isn't working and I can't seem to fix it

Comment: The above answers code I am currently working and its worked well.